# Distinct Reversible Primitive Binary Necklaces

Tags: code-golf, math, sequence, combinatorics

## Introduction - What is a necklace?

A necklace is something that OEIS people are obsessed with. The OEIS challenge has like 5 necklace sequences.

A binary necklace of length `n` is a loop with `n` beads that are either `0` or `1`. Two necklaces are the same if one can be rotated to become the other, and two reversible necklaces are the same if one can be rotated, reversed, or reversed and rotated to become the other.

A primitive necklace is one that cannot be expressed as more than one copy of a string of beads chained together. Note that the copies must be assembled all in the same order (no reversing) for a necklace to be considered non-primitive.

For example, let's take a look at this necklace: `0 1 1 0 1 1`. It is not primitive because it can be expressed as `0 1 1` repeated twice. `0 1 0 1 1` is primitive.

`0 1 1 0` is primitive because `0 1` and `1 0` are not considered the same string. This necklace is equivalent to `1 1 0 0` because it can be rotated left one bead to become this one, but not equivalent to `0 1 0 1` (which isn't primitive by the way).

## Challenge

Given an non-negative integer `n`, return the number of distinct reversible primitive binary necklaces of length `n`. Input and output as a single integer each.

The first few terms of this sequence are `1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 6, 8, 16, 24, 42, 69, 124, 208, 378, 668, 1214, 2220, 4110`, 0-indexed.

**This is [OEIS A001371](http://oeis.org/A001371)**

[Reference Implementation in Python 3](https://tio.run/##hVPLboMwELz3K7Y3Ow1NIDck/qI3hCo32I0VZ6HGNO3XU@OAzSNVOFjg3Z3dmVnqX3Oq8NB1JRcgCNL0CeyD/HhW7MgbyCDP9wVsAAsXcYeoNEiQCJrhJycJbGwcIoiH8v45tlpzNBbAg@VRXORp4VMklvzHJkSxv7qepOLwplsekFyqGAFzV1VAlsF@njPpOia9ZBCvcj40Z@fZLVcNf4hl@61SbgyiaRfP9pXVNceSDDA0yNdrXWt5edfsSsb8iXSam1YjMKWID@cp9i4QxTGUwG4HSCk8B5GdNxi8ibcwK6GLOXRlmJEVNncHqYzbgGDZwvk59FzCvnjUwLOQqTUFAilZ0H@L@vfbyqT2pEt5@vBaU2nkN38gqtd@JE8dr/HL0VvLshCOf7VMEbT6YrJug/ECJZmUC4lMBV39L@U9tKV@jQK0vMsQGJaOFVZmGErgFkK8RxaOlOu7cMndLW2azDrw6Y2@lXd2BjREycaQC6uJ2IZNixO7X7Q7/AE) - quite slow

Comment: Oh, I get it—"primitive" means it can't be partially rotated to get the original necklace, right?

Comment: @ETHproductions ... I never thought of it that way. Yes, that is definitely a correct understanding. Nice!

Comment: Why is `0 1 0 1` primitive? Isn't it `0 1` repeated twice?

Comment: @MishaLavrov Thanks; I meant "not primitive" whoops. Thanks

Comment: ಠ_ಠ I was looking for an OEIS sequence to post as a challenge and the next thing I see is... this... necklaces. ._.

Comment: @icrieverytim see I had to suffer the first necklace question with unknown terms that almost killed the challenge, so time for revenge mwahahaha

Comment: Trying to do this manually for n = 7 before I try to code it, and coming up two short. A string of all 0's or all 1's is not primitive right? That said, I do get 16 if I count those strings that cannot be reversed to get themselves.

Comment: @Tahg The sixteen I get are: `0000001`, `0000011`, `0000101`, `0000111`, `0001001`, `0001011`, `0001111`, `0010011`, `0010101`, `0010111`, `0011011`, `0011111`, `0101011`, `0101111`, `0110111`, `0111111`

Comment: @HyperNeutrino, what's your definition of "almost killed the challenge"? By [my criteria](http://data.stackexchange.com/codegolf/query/726970) you've saved the chain two times but they had nothing to do with necklaces.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I guess "killed the challenge" wouldn't be the right way to word it; something like the first one that involved weird math that needed Math.SE to complete (but even then I'm not sure it was the first lol... hm)

Comment: Ok, it seems like I was just confused on the definition of a reversible primitive.  I had in mind a number that, when reversed, could be rotated to be itself, but rereading the question doesn't seem to imply that at all.  In the case of n = 7, 14/16 had this property of symmetry, though I couldn't find an OEIS that matched that.

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>178</s> <s>171</s> <s>139</s> 137 bytes

```python
lambda n:sum(1-any(i>int(b[j::-1]+b[:j:-1],2)or j*(i>=int(b[j:]+b[:j],2))for j in range(n))for i in range(2**n)for b in[bin(i+2**n)[3:]])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYxBDoMgFESvwvKjmFS6I7EXQRaQlvYT@RK0C09PRdt0N3lvZtK2vmaSxQ9jmWx0d8tILe8IfWdpA7whreB0UKrrTeu0CjUIyefMQrP74Vc4bVXcV8mQWLb0fACdBP9ENg0dzO1MOyTA9mD6qozhJeX6OuGyQrQJvPjuLoL1@z/n5QM) Edit: Saved <s>7</s> 21 bytes thanks to @HalvardHummel.

Comment: [157 bytes](https://tio.run/##TY2xDoIwFEV3v6LjK2AidavBH6kd2kDxNfAgpQws/notaKLzOfeeeYvPiURyzSMNZrStYSSXdYQeqELupsCQIbFgqO9AFAVxfmo7xz5c2sYiAZYHUVepb6GLa6CXoQ3wjhQBrPJSl1ZJr7mS8lzrSvB87ItsNLvyZ2R0VP2vmpOlSHPYzQGXCKOZwVVfeqlYnTecpzc)

Comment: @HalvardHummel Thanks, I couldn't work out how to generate all the permutations in a 1-liner.

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>198</s> 192 bytes

I was curious to know what a fully mathematical answer would look like. So here it is. Quite long but very fast.

```js
n=>(g=d=>d&&(n%d?0:(q=n/d,C=(a,b)=>b?C(b,a%b):a<2,M=n=>n%++k?k>n?(q%2+3)/4*(1<<q/2)+(R=d=>d&&(q%d?0:(P=k=>k--&&C(q/d,k)+P(k))(q/d)<<d)+R(d-1))(q)/q/2:M(n):n/k%k&&-M(n/k))(d,k=1))+g(d-1))(n)||1
```

#### Demo

```js
let f =

n=>(g=d=>d&&(n%d?0:(q=n/d,C=(a,b)=>b?C(b,a%b):a<2,M=n=>n%++k?k>n?(q%2+3)/4*(1<<q/2)+(R=d=>d&&(q%d?0:(P=k=>k--&&C(q/d,k)+P(k))(q/d)<<d)+R(d-1))(q)/q/2:M(n):n/k%k&&-M(n/k))(d,k=1))+g(d-1))(n)||1

for(n = 0; n <= 30; n++) {
  console.log('a(' + n + ') = ' + f(n))
}
```

#### How?

This is based on the following formulas:

```
A000029(n) =
  (n % 2 + 3) / 4 * 2 ** floor(n / 2) +
  sum(φ(n / d) * 2 ** d, for d in divisors(n)) / (2 * n)

A001371(n) =
  1 if n = 0
  sum(μ(d) * A000029(n / d), for d in divisors(n)) if n > 0
```

Where ***φ*** is [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function) and ***μ*** is [Möbius function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function).

```js
n => (g = d =>
  // if d = 0, stop the recursion of g()
  d && (
    // if d is not a divisor of n, ignore this iteration
    n % d ? 0 :
    (
      // define q = n / d, C = function that tests whether a and b are coprime,
      // M = Möbius function (requires k to be initialized to 1)
      q = n / d,
      C = (a, b) => b ? C(b, a % b) : a < 2,
      M = n => n % ++k ? k > n || M(n) : n / k % k && -M(n / k)
    )(d, k = 1) * ( // invoke M with d
      // first part of the formula for A000029
      (q % 2 + 3) / 4 * (1 << q / 2) +
      // 2nd part of the formula for A000029
      (R = d =>
        // if d = 0, stop the recursion of R()
        d && (
          // if d is not a divisor of q, ignore this iteration
          q % d ? 0 :
          // compute phi(q / d) * 2 ** d
          (P = k => k-- && C(Q, k) + P(k))(Q = q / d) << d
        // recursive call to R()
        ) + R(d - 1)
      )(q) / q / 2 // invoke R with q, and divide the result by q * 2
    )
  // recursive call to g()
  ) + g(d - 1)
)(n) || 1
```

NB: In the current golfed version, the 2nd part of the code is now directly embedded inside ***M()***. But that makes the code harder to read.

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica, <s>128</s> <s>125</s> <s>124</s> <s>109</s> 99 bytes

```
1~Max~(L=Length)@(U=Union)[U[#,Reverse/@#]&/@MaximalBy[U@Partition[#,L@#,1,1]&/@{0,1}~Tuples~#,L]]&
```

### How it works

- `{0,1}~Tuples~#` finds all binary sequences of the given length
- `U@Partition[#,L@#,1,1]&/@...` finds all possible rotations of each one of them
- `MaximalBy[...,L]` picks out the entries with the most distinct rotations; these correspond to the primitive necklaces.
- `U[#,Reverse/@#]&/@...` puts the rotations in each entry, and their reversals, into a canonical order...
- `(L=Length)@(U=Union)[...]` ...so that we can delete duplicate primitive necklaces, and then count the elements remaining.
- `1~Max~...` we make sure the result is at least 1 to get the zeroth term right.

---

*-2 bytes thanks to Jonathan Frech, and -2 thanks to me learning from him*

*-15 more bytes from switching to* `MaximalBy` *and related changes*

*-10 from switching to* `Partition`

Comment: I think if you replace `Length` with `L` and define `L=Length;`, you could save a byte.

Comment: [126 bytes](https://tio.run/##JcqxCoMwEIDhhwmEFg5qhk42EOhUyFCsncINVs6qaCzx7CLm1VOKy798/1hx29VzuofOsymr10DukKy25N/c5rfGiYsCBUHvJmIxccVkqeHIsDJYJ3BDmVvz9N3k3d5gBART0JfCTEagPJkHDVSzWzNQWyyXz0Bz/E8iXqfFcxRaK4mIMh1dj7D2kMF5w/QD).

Comment: 125, since I forgot to golf one of the instances of Length. Thanks!

Comment: And now it's 124, since I have learned from your example and turned another `==1` into a `<2`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 21 bytes

```
Ṡ#▲mLüOmȯṁSe↔U¡ṙ1ΠRḋ2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATkAxv9odXNr/yBt4oKBOjDhuKMxMP/huaAj4paybUzDvE9tyK/huYFTZeKGlFXCoeG5mTHOoFLhuIsy//8)
The link shows results from 0 to 10.

### Explanation

```
Ṡ#▲mLüOmȯṁSe↔U¡ṙ1ΠRḋ2  Implicit input, say n=4.
                  Rḋ2  The list [1,0] repeated n times: [[1,0],[1,0],[1,0],[1,0]]
                 Π     Cartesian product: [[1,1,1,1],[0,1,1,1],[1,0,1,1],...,[0,0,0,0]]
       mȯ              For each list, say x=[0,1,0,0]:
              ¡ṙ1        Iterate rotation by one step: [[0,1,0,0],[1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1],[0,0,1,0],[0,1,0,0],...
             U           Take prefix of unique values: [[0,1,0,0],[1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1],[0,0,1,0]]
         ṁSe↔            After each element, insert its reversal: [[0,1,0,0],[0,0,1,0],[1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1],[0,0,0,1],[1,0,0,0],[0,0,1,0],[0,1,0,0]]
     üO                Remove duplicates with respect to sorting.
   mL                  Get length of each list of lists.
Ṡ#▲                    Count the number of maximal lengths.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 25 bytes

```
2ḶṗµṙJ;U$ṢḢµ€QµsJṖE€ẸṆµ€S
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/o4Y5tD3dOP7T14c6ZXtahKg93Lnq4Y9GhrY@a1gQe2lrs9XDnNFcg@@GuHQ93toGFg////29oBgA)

Very inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript (ES7), 180 bytes

```js
n=>[...Array(2**n)].filter((_,m)=>![...m=m.toString(2).padStart(n,0)].some(_=>s[m=m.replace(/(.)(.*)/,"$2$1")]|s[[...m].reverse().join``])&!/^(.+)\1+$/.test(m)&(s[m]=1),s=[]).length
```

Explanation:

```js
n=>[...Array(2**n)].filter((_,m)=>(     // For every number m from 0 to 2^n-1
    m=m.toString(2).padStart(n,0),      // Take the binary representation (padded)

    ![...m].some(_=>(                   // Repeat once for every digit in m
        m=m.replace(/(.)(.*)/,"$2$1"),  // Rotate m one step
        s[m]|s[[...m].reverse().join``] // Search for m and the reverse of m in the
    ))                                  // lookup table

    &!/^(.+)\1+$/.test(m)               // Test if m is primitive
    &(s[m]=1)                           // Add m to the lookup table

),s=[]).length                          // Get the length of the list of numbers that
                                        // satisfy the above conditions
```

```js
f=n=>[...Array(2**n)].filter((_,m)=>![...m=m.toString(2).padStart(n,0)].some(_=>s[m=m.replace(/(.)(.*)/,"$2$1")]|s[[...m].reverse().join``])&!/^(.+)\1+$/.test(m)&(s[m]=1),s=[]).length
```

```html
<input id=i type=number value=5/><button onclick="o.innerText=f(i.value)">Test</button><br><pre id=o></pre>
```